Can someone help me know how to integrate liquibase in bitbucket pipeline?
I am planning to use liquibase for my database migration. I have succesfully installed the bitbucket in local machine and tested everything. Now It is the time when I want to automate the database migraiton. Hence I thought to install the liquibase in the pipeline environment and then run the liquibase update command. I tried all possible ways however it did not work for me. Is there anyone who can help me. Thanks!

pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Dev:Build and Deploy
          caches:
            - node
          deployment: dev
          script:
            - printf "Preparing Serverless deployment for Dev..."
            - npm install
            - npm install --save serverless-iam-roles-per-function
            - npm run build
            - printf "Setting up Liquibase...\n"
            # Check if Liquibase is cached, if not download and cache it
            - |
              if [ ! -d "liquibase" ]; then
                  # Download Liquibase
                  wget -q https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/download/v4.20.0/liquibase-4.20.0.tar.gz

                  # Check if download was successful
                  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "File downloaded successfully."

                    # Create the liquibase directory
                    mkdir -p liquibase

                    # Extract the tar.gz file directly into the liquibase directory
                    tar -xvzf liquibase-4.20.0.tar.gz -C liquibase --strip-components=1

                    # List directory contents to verify extraction
                    echo "list liquibase folder contents"
                    ls -l liquibase
                    which liquibase
                  else
                    echo "Failed to download Liquibase. Exiting."
                    exit 1
                  fi
                else
                  printf "Liquibase already cached.\n"
                fi
            - export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/liquibase
            - printf "Running Liquibase migration...\n"
            # Run Liquibase migrations
            - liquibase --url="jdbc:postgresql://$DB_HOST:5432/$DB_NAME" \
              --username=$DB_USER \
              --password=$DB_PASS \
              --changeLogFile=master-changelogs.xml \
              update
            - printf "Liquibase migration completed.\n"

            - npm run prisma:generate
          #  - npm install --only=production
            - pipe: atlassian/serverless-deploy:1.2.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                EXTRA_ARGS: '--stage dev --region us-west-2 --verbose'


why not just liquibase -> ./liquibase/liquibase ? echo "list liquibase folder contents" so what is inside the directory?
